# Adding music into LibGDX isn't working. Get an error saying that newMusic isn't a method Has anyone else had this problem lately?

Tags: java, libgdx

```
intro = new Audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("core/assets/OpenSong.mp3"));
```

In the javadocs this is how it says to do it

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Music.html

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Audio.html#newMusic-com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle-

Here: https://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/11/19/LibGDX-Tutorial-8-Audio.aspx they used a lowercase audio instead of uppercase but when changing it to lower case that didn't work either.

It's as if audio/Audio just don't have that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should import the class `com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx` and then you can use

```
intro = Gfx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("core/assets/OpenSong.mp3"));
```

Alternatively you can write

```
// where all the import statements live
import static com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx.audio;

//  where you try to load the music
intro = audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("core/assets/OpenSong.mp3"));
```

Your code tries to create a new `Audio` instance (this will not work, since `Audio` is just an interface - you would need to create an implementation for it).

Just replacing `new Audio` with `audio` will also not work (unless you statically import `com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx.audio`, as in the second example) - `audio` alone would mean a field or local variable `audio`.